# Why does this sql snippet return 8 or 1 always?

Tags: sql, count, common-table-expression, cross-join

What is the result of:

```
WITH Tbl AS (SELECT 5 AS A UNION SELECT 6 AS A) 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tbl FROM Tbl AS A, Tbl AS B, Tbl AS C;
```

I know the result is supposed to be 8 but I don't know why. Also when I change both values (the 5 or 6) to the same thing it returns a table with the value 1 instead of 8 but all other instances it returns 8 no matter what numbers if they are different. I tested it out with an online sql executor.

Comment: Note that if you used `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` it would always answer 8. The UNION removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the query does:

- the common table expression (the subquery within the `with` clause) generates a derived table made of two rows
- then, in the outer query, the `from` clause generates a cartesian product of this resultset twice: that's a total of 8 rows (`2 * 2 * 2`)
- the `select` clause counts the number of rows - that's `8`

The content of the rows in the `with` clause does not matter: this `5` and `6` could very well be `foo` and `bar`, or `null` and `null`, the result would be the same.

What makes a difference is the number of *rows* that the `with` clause generates. If it was generating just one row, you would get `1` as a result (`1 * 1 * 1`). If it was generating 3 rows, you would get `27` - and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was pretty helpful.

Comment: I just have a follow-up question, if you don't mind... it might have to do with how cartesian products work.

What do you mean it generates a cartesian product of this resultset twice? It seems to me the expressions after FROM is just setting A, B, and C to Tbl which is two, and I am guessing that Count(*) is just specifying to multiply each of these. I don't know where the twice comes in as I just see three numbers being multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
WITH Tbl AS (SELECT 5 AS A UNION SELECT 6 AS A)
```

creates a (derived) table with two rows.

This expression:

```
WITH Tbl AS (SELECT 5 AS A UNION SELECT 5 AS A)
```

creates a (derived) table with one row, because `UNION` removes duplicates.

The rest of the query just counts the number of rows in the 3-way Cartesian product, which is either 1*1*1 or 2*2*2.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had no idea Union removed duplicates like that.